# Integrate Paypal recurring payment for android

Tags: android, paypal

I want to integrate recurrent payment for one of my android application via paypal but didn't find any straight forward way to implement this to my app.
I've tried using paypal's future payment and become confused about the difference between recurrent payment and future payment. I need two information.

1. What is the difference between paypal's 'Future Payment' & 'Recurrent Payment' ?
2. How to implement recurrent payment ? Any suggestion or links describes the feature ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recurring payment is one that is scheduled on a regular interval, and does not require a user be present for the transaction.  The user will approve a billing agreement for those transactions.

A future payment is one in which the user approves the payment, but from the merchant app or website, and need not login.

A recurring payment or a future payment can both be revoked from a user's PayPal settings.

Take a look at [this doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPRecurringPayments/) for integrating recurring payments.